# infrastructure diagram without graphviz dependency

Tags: python, visualization

I'd like to create an **infrastructure diagram using Python**.

So far, I found diagram packages such as `diagrams` for Python using `graphviz` as a backend. As graphviz needs os-specific installation steps (pip install is not sufficient), I'd prefer to use a solution **without graphviz dependency**.

An example could be `diagram`'s [quick start](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/docs/getting-started/installation#quick-start) example:
[image: diagram's quick start example requiring graphviz backend]

Comment: I've distributed graphviz without requiring installation before. You can just place the exe file in the same directory as your python scripts. The python graphviz module can be set to use the current directory for the graphviz exe.

Comment: @scotty3785 It sounds like an unexpected, but interesting solution to my problem. Could you elaborate your comment as an answer?